# Does Apache pig have a Unit Test capability that also provides code coverage and links to Jira?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, apache-pig, code-coverage, jira-plugin

We are assessing the use of pig on our project.

We use jUnit with Netbeans and Jira for tracking.

Does pig (pUnit, other) have a unit test that provides code covrage metrics and interfaces with Jira.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this link will help you to get some info about pig unit testing and code coverage. I never tried but you can give a try.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/test.html#pigunit

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/HowToTest#HowToTest-GeneratingCodeCoverageNumbersforUnitTests